# Why when changing resolution while the game is running through the exe built file everything is too blurry and the ui not respond?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas, resolution, screen-resolution

[image: Blurry]

The default resolution is 1920x1080 and the ui elements are sharp and fine. Once I changed the resolution to 640x480 but it's the same on other resolutions either everything get blurry and the buttons are not responding all I can click on is the RESOLUTION dropdown and change the resolution and if I will change it back to the defalut 1920x1080 then everything will be looking sharp again and I will be able to click on the buttons and change all other ui's.

How can I fix it so on any resolution it will looks sharp and also will respond ?

This is how it looks like on the default 1920x1080 :

[image: 1920x1080]

This is my Main Menu hierarchy :

[image: Main Menu hierarchy]

And the script that attached to the Canvas :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public Text volumeInPercentages;
    public Dropdown resolutionDropDown;

    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _volumeSlider;
    [SerializeField]
    private Dropdown _dropDownQuality;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Start()
    {
        resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
        resolutionDropDown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height
                 + " " + resolutions[i].refreshRate.ToString() + " Hz";
            options.Add(option);

            if (resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropDown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropDown.value = currentResolutionIndex;
        resolutionDropDown.RefreshShownValue();
    }

    public void SetVolume()
    {
        float volume = _volumeSlider.value;
        Debug.Log("Volume " + volume);
        audioMixer.SetFloat("MusicVol", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        volumeInPercentages.text = Mathf.Round(volume * 100).ToString() + " %";
    }

    public void SetQuality()
    {
        int qualityIndex = _dropDownQuality.value;
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullScreen()
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = !Screen.fullScreen;
    }

    public void SetResolution()
    {
        Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionDropDown.value];
        Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem with your .exe file.

1. Right Click on the exe
2. Select Properties
3. Click change High DPI settings under Compatibility
4. Select Override high dpi scaling behavior and select scaling performed by application.

   Hopefully that works for you.